# Pandas for data merging from two excel sheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to match two excel sheets based on columns value, 
i started writing this code:

```
import pandas as pd
transit = "C\\Users\\Taqwa\\Desktop\\dta_coded\\data.xlsx"
xlsx = pd.ExcelFile(transit)
df = pd.read_excel(xlsx,"201705_ch2m","zonUnsom163")
```

the following error appears:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: What are the 2nd and 3rd args to `read_excel`?

Comment: where are the column of your second excel sheets?

Answer (score 0):

If you have two separate excel files with same column name you can compare it by the following method

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel('file1.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('file2.xlsx')

diff = df1[df1!=df2]
print (diff)
```